# How to get the ID of button contained in parent page from User Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control contained within a page that has a button.

I want to use FindControl() to see if the button exists in the parent page, but the button doesn't have an ID.

I have tried the following code:

```
Page.Master.FindControl("ButtonName/Text on button here?")
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: If the button is a Server Control it must have an ID

Comment: If it's created dynamically? How do you find out what the ID is?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? 2, 3, 3.5, 4.0?

Comment: just a poor workaround, you could get all the button controls on the page and then compare the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it's created dynamically? How do you find out what the ID is?

If the button was created dynamically then YOU should manually assign it an ID.

Example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button btnFound = (Button)this.FindControl("myButton");
    if (btnFound != null)
    {
        Response.Write("Found It!");
    }
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = new Button()
    {
        ID = "myButton",
        Text = "Click Me"
    };

    this.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use FindControl() to see if the button exists in the parent
>   page, but the button doesn't have an ID.

You won't be able to find it using `FindControl` since this requires that the element has an ID and that this button is a server control (ie runat="server" is set in the markup)

The only thing you can do in a scenario like this is to use client-side scripting to find the element, using plain javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're talking about an asp:Button, you could do a recursive find if you wanted to search by the text.

Master Page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
 <head runat="server">
     <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <form runat="server">
     <div>
         <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTest" Text="Test Button" />
             <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And a snipet of code to do a recursive find

```
    protected List<Control> FindButton(ControlCollection controls, string buttonText)
    {
       List<Control> foundControls = (from c in controls.Cast<Control>() where c is Button && ((Button)c).Text == "Test Button" select c).ToList();

       if (foundControls.Count > 0)
           return foundControls;
       else
       {
           foreach (Control ctrl in controls)
           {

               if (foundControls.Count == 0)
                   foundControls = FindButton(ctrl.Controls, buttonText);

               if (foundControls.Count > 0)
                break;

           }
           return foundControls;
       }
    }
```

And then use:

```
        List<Control> buttons = FindButton(Page.Master.Controls, "Test Button");
        if (buttons.Count > 0)
        {
            ((Button)buttons[0]).Text = "I found it";
        }
```

This code could be modified in several ways, like instead of stopping after find any buttons, continue the loop finding ALL buttons. It could also be changed to find only a single button and return it instead of a List of controls. You could also modify your query to find controls of a different type.